# Decrypt PBE encrypted passwords with Postgres SQL

Tags: java, postgresql, cryptography, javax.crypto

I have an application which uses the Java javax.crypto package to encrypt strings and store them in a postgresql database. We need to decrypt these strings from postgres SQL. I know of the postgresSQL package pgcrypto but I don't know which of the pgcrypto functions I should use to decrypt the strings. The java code uses a Crypto "PBEWithMD5AndDES" algorithm and I can't find a corresponding algorithm(s) in the pgcrypto package.

For example, if the private key is 'a_private_key' then the application code uses the following functions to generate the secret key and to encrypt a string.

```
SecretKey secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec("a_private_key".toCharArray()));
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES")
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, 
            new PBEParameterSpec(
               new byte[] { (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x33,
                            (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0x37, },
               15);
byte[] crypted = cipher.doFinal("StringToEncrypt".getBytes(UTF8));
```

Comment: I remember reading into this extensively for another question a while ago, but I can't find it. Basically, the key derivation functions used in the PBE algorithms are non-standard, and you won't find them anywhere except Java.

Comment: From the Java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html  PBEWithMD5AndDES: The password-based encryption algorithm as defined in RSA Laboratories, "PKCS #5: Password-Based Encryption Standard," version 1.5, Nov 1993. Note that this algorithm implies CBC as the cipher mode and PKCS5Padding as the padding scheme and cannot be used with any other cipher modes or padding schemes. BTW if you really need encryption then DES probably isn't good enough anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, looks like I need to rethink the design now. Sorry but I don't know how to 'up vote' your answers as they are comments.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question now as the comments by ntoskml and Eilke are correct; PBE is a java only cryptography and hence I could not decrypt it from Postgresql.
So in the end I had to come up a Java/JDBC solution to the problem.